# How to break Lodash nested loops

Tags: lodash

What will be the best way to break Lodash nested loops?

PS Alternative way of doing the nested loops with Lodash to avoid the problem is also an option.

Here is the example pseudo code:

```
function findItem(elements:any,itemName:string):boolean
{
   let result = false;
   _.forEach(elements,(element:any)=>{
           _.forEach(element.items, (item:any) => {
              if(item.name === itemName)
              {
                 result = true;
                 return false; // here will exit only the current forEach !!!
              }
           }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you can use a combine of `_.forEach()` with [`_.find()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find), since `_.find()` returns immediately, when a predicate returns `true`. When `_.find()` returns a result, assign it to `result`, and return `false` to exit the `_.forEach()`:

```
function findItem(elements: any, itemName: string): boolean {
  let result = null;
  _.forEach(elements, (element: any) => {
    const res = _.find(element.items, item => item.name === itemName);

    if(res) {
      result = res;
      return false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

In vanilla JS/typescript, you can use nested [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops, and return the item when you find it:

```
function findItem(elements: any, itemName: string): boolean {
  for(const el of elements) {
    for(const item of el.items) {
      if (item.name === itemName) {
        return item;
      }
    }  
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label very helpful.

If you instead use conventional `for of` loops, you can label them and `continue/break` based on label

```
function findItem(elements: any, itemName: string): boolean {
  outer:
  for(const el of elements) {
    innner:
    for(const item of el.items) {
        //can 'break outer' here.
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is OK, if you just create for loops but not if you use Lodash. There you can't have a loop identirfier as long as I know.